# Quarkus docker container failed to run / connect to the DB

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, containers, quarkus

In my project, using Quarkus, Angular and PostgreSQL DB, when I run the backend & and the frontend in dev Mode, I can connect to the DB (which is postgreSQL image running in a docker container) and create new lines in the tables and just works fine.
Of course the Quarkus docker file is auto-generated.
Here is the "application.properties" file I typed (inside the Quarkus project) :

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username= username
quarkus.datasource.password= pwd
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db-mcs-thirdparty
quarkus.flyway.migrate-at-start=true
quarkus.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
quarkus.flyway.out-of-order=false
quarkus.flyway.baseline-version=1
```

and this is the "docker-compose.yml" file which I placed inside the backend folder (Quarkus):

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    container_name: pg_container
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pwd
      POSTGRES_DB: db-mcs-thirdparty
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  pgadmin:
      container_name: pgadmin4_container
      image: dpage/pgadmin4
      restart: always
      environment:
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: usernamepgadmin
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: pwdpgadmin
      ports:
        - "5050:80"
```

But when I build a Quarkus docker image and try to run it in docker container, it fails !! knowing that the Angular docker container runs well, also the DB.
Here the error logs which I get after running the container:

Starting the Java application using /opt/jboss/container/java/run/run-java.sh ...

```
__  ____  __  _____   ___  __ ____  ______
 --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/
 -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/

2022-05-06 12:58:31,967 WARN  [io.agr.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource '<default>': The connection attempt failed.
2022-05-06 12:58:32,015 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (main) Failed to start application (with profile prod): java.net.UnknownHostException: db

at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:229)
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:241)
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:109)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:400)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:259)
at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:210)
at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:513)
at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:494)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1126)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

So I replaced "localhost" in the:

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db-mcs-thirdparty
```

with the IP address, with the DB's name, even I tried to enter the user name and the psw in that same line, etc ...., but didn't work.

I even stopped all the running containers (DB, frontend) and tried to run only the Quarkus container, the same case happens.
For the ports that I used, you can check the attached image.
[the used ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3BRi.jpg)

How should resolve this issue? thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello, quarkus couldn't find host "db", where does this come from ?

Comment: It comes from the "docker-compose.yml" file; line n°3

Comment: How is this deployed? 
Did you start the database and the angular application with `docker-compose` command and then start the quarkus container with a `docker run` command?

Comment: @BamKenobi, in the ```docker-compose``` I just mentioned the postgres DB container and the pg_admin4 container in order to have access to a web interface.
For the frontend app, I'm running it inside a docker container.
For the quarkus container, yes I do run it with ```docker run``` command, in fact the same case with angular ```docker run```

Answer (score 1):

The `localhost` url stated in `application.properties` file refers to the containers own system localhost. That means your quarkus application container looking for this port on its own local ports.

As far as i know, every `docker-container` and every started `docker-compose.yaml` create their own network, and only within this network the started services can connect through their service-names.

Therefore your quarkus docker container has to connect to the services started by docker-compose. One solution could be to define all services (database, angular and backend) in one docker-compose.yaml and then refers to the service names in your url.

Another solution could be using `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost`.

May further information regarding docker networks and `host.docker.internal` stated here: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking/

Answer (score 1):

You can run your Quarkus container with network mode host (`--network host`), like this example:

```
$ docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx
```

https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/

You could also add your Quarkus to your docker-compose like this example:

https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/blob/main/kafka-quickstart/docker-compose.yaml